# Hide is not working in Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, hide

I am not a techie in terms of html or ajax or javascript. But i had to develop a script. My problem is "hide" is not working in my ajax.
I have 2 text field that gives the search result. I want to hide the search suggestion (in "ul" tag) of one when the user searches in the other.

Below given is the javascript and html

```js
function autocomplet() {
 var min_length = 0; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
 var keyword = $('#country_id').val();
 if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
  $.ajax({
   url: 'ajax_refresh.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {keyword:keyword},
   success:function(data){
    $('#country_list_id').show();
    $('#country_list_id').html(data);
   }
  });
 } else {
  $('#country_list_id').hide();
 }

 document.getElementById('house_list_id').style.display = 'none';
}

function autocomplet_house() {
 
 var min_length = 0; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
 var keyword = $('#house_id').val();
 if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
  $.ajax({
   url: 'ajax_refresh_house.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {keyword:keyword},
   success:function(data){
    $('#house_list_id').show();
    $('#house_list_id').html(data);
   }
  });
 } else {
  $('#house_list_id').hide();
 }

 document.getElementById('country_list_id').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
     <form>
                <div class="label_div">Search Name:&nbsp </div>
                <div class="input_container">
                    <input type="text" id="country_id" name="country_name" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="autocomplet()">
                    <ul id="country_list_id"></ul>
                </div>

                 <div class="label_div">Search House:&nbsp </div>
                <div class="input_container">
                    <input type="text" id="house_id" name="house_name" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="autocomplet_house()">
                    <ul id="house_list_id"></ul>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a hide-condition, that is never met:

```
var min_length = 0;

if (keyword.length >= min_length){
    /* keyword is always zero length or greater */
} else {
    /* will never reach here */
}
```

Besides, I think you want to hide 'the other list', when showing the 'current list' ... Try changing your ajax-success like this:

```
success:function(data){
    $('#country_list_id').html(data).show();
    $('#house_list_id').hide();
}

success:function(data){
    $('#house_list_id').html(data).show();
    $('#country_list_id').hide();
}
```

Comment: Hai Ole, first of all, thank you for your help. But i am worried about the hide calling by javascript. "document.getElementById('country_list_id').style.display = 'none';"

Comment: Not working :(, I've read somewhere that the ajax execution so fast and that might the cause for this. any thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Ok ... I have been thinking, and have rearranged everything.

Try this:

```
<script>
    function autocomplet(Elm){
        var Name = Elm.attr('name');
        var Word = Elm.val();
        var ListA = $('#'+Name+'_list_id');
        var ListB = Elm.parents('form').find('ul').not(ListA).hide();

        var min = 0; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
        if( Word.length >= min ){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax_refresh_'+Name+'.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {Word:Word},
                success:function(data){
                    ListA.empty().html(data).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>

<form>
    <div class="label_div">Search Name:&nbsp</div>
    <div class="input_container">
        <input type="text" name="country" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="autocomplet($(this));">
        <ul id="country_list_id"></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="label_div">Search House:&nbsp</div>
    <div class="input_container">
        <input type="text" name="house" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="autocomplet($(this));">
        <ul id="house_list_id"></ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I am so sorry OLA. I've wasted your time. my code was actually working. I did not clear the browsing history. so Chrome was keeping the old javascript and it was not taking my new edits. Old one was doing only the displaying part, not the hiding.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot OLA, you gave me an idea to reduce the redundancy of the code. I've Cleared my browsing history and it worked.